# PHP - .htaccess and GET parameters

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to create a simple redirect to another page on login script.

Currently I am rewriting my URLS to the following format using `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^login$ ?i=l [L]
RewriteRule ^login([^/]*)$ ?i=l&=$1
```

The normal URL is therefore: `domain.com/login` - although I wish to be able to do the following: `domain.com/login&redirect=/account/settings` (Where the "redirect" will be the `$_GET` parameter that I'll be redirecting to after successful login)

My problem is if I access the above URL I get a 404 page not found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You confuse `&` and `?` as it looks... An `&` cannot be part of the url itself. It would have to be "percent encoded".

Comment: Shouldn't a `?` separate the parameters from the path in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$ ?i=l [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^login(&[^/]+)/?$ ?i=l$1 [L,NC]
```

Though I suggest using:

```
domain.com/login?redirect=/account/settings
```

and get rid of 2nd rule altogether.

`QSA` flag in first rule will add `redirect=/account/settings` query parameter as `$_GET` to your php file.

Answer (score 0):

I use a `.htaccess`.
It's more functional and simple. I do not know if that's what you need but the handling is very simple.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1 [L,NC]
```

**Url Example :**

```
domain.com/login/account/settings
```

**The treatment is in the script PHP**

```
$param = $_GET['param'];
echo $param;
```

**Return**

```
login/account/settings
```

**Or then**

```
$param = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
// (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0)
// $param = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'RESQUEST_URI');
$param = explode('/',$param);
print_r($param);
```

**Return**

```
Array( [0]=> [1]=>login [2]=>account [3]=>settings)
```

With this method it is possible to accomplish several goals.